# Best procedure to modify Inmutable Spark RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In the past, I worked with low level parallelization (openmpi, openmp,...)

I am currently working in a Spark project and I don't know the best procedure to work with RDDs because they are inmutable.

I will explain my problem with a simple example, imagine that in my RDD I have an object and I need to update one attribute.

The most practical and memory efficient way to solve this is implementing a method called setAttribute(new_value).

Spark RDDs are inmutable, so I need to create a function (for example myModifiedCopy(new_value)) that returns a copy of this object but with the new_value in its attribute and updating the RDD like this:

```
myRDD = myRDD.map(x->x.myModifiedCopy(new_value)).cache()
```

My objects are very complex and they use a lot of RAM memory (they are really huge). This procedure is slow, you have to create a complete copy of every element of the RDD just to modify an small value.

Is there a better procedure to deal with this kind of problems?

Do you recommend a different technology?

I would kill for a mutable RDD.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You might need to checkout http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: You can store your RDD on DISK or OFF_HEAP, if memory is the only problem.

Comment: If memory is the problem, then I wouldn't cache it. I would just use more partitions with the property `spark.default.parallelism`. But I think this is not the main problem he want to solve?

Comment: My priority is the speed, so the disk is discarded. My RDD is no very big in elements. But it contains really big objects (300MB of RAM each one) and a very simple operation like updating an attribute that is an string is slow and is not memory efficient because I need to replicate the whole object for a small change. Furthermore, I need to do a lot of changes in time, so I need to use count() or cache() in every change because if I don't do that the reduce is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you have some misconceptions of `Apache Spark`. When you do a transformation, indeed you aren't creating a whole copy of that `RDD` in memory, you are just "designing" the series of tiny conversions to execute in each record when you run an action. 
For instance, `map`, `filter` and `flatMap` are entirely transformations, thus lazy, so when you execute them you just design the plan but don't execute it. On the other hand, `collect` or `count` behave differently they *trigger* all previous transformations (doing everything that was defined in the intermediate *stages*) until they get the result.

Comment: My procedure is a loop, in every iteration I call a map / reduce operation and I modify some variables in the RDD using the result of the reduce and other external variables. I call count() or cache() in every iteration because the reduce() operation is very slow after some iterations if I don't do that.

Comment: How many iterations? What exactly are you tying to achieve? I think that those information changed the context completely.

Comment: The number of iterations may change. The algorithm has to converge. More or less a minimum of 50 iterations and a maximum of 1000. That is the reason why I need to call cache() or count() every iteration. My approach is inneficient, I know, maybe a differet approach is better, maybe a different technology. I don't know.

Comment: Would it be a option to represent your huge objects with a dataframe like a table in a database? It could be more efficient with spark sql.